# List comprehension in list within a list (dimensions are different than usual)

Tags: python

I'm trying to flatten the list using list comprehension below but it's not working any suggestions will help. thanks

```
list = [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]
```

tried doing list = [x for x in list] outputs the initial list and [x for x in list for y in list] repeats the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a recursive function:

```
import collections

def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)]
    else:
        return [x]
        
            
list = [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]
print(flatten(list))
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks @Aymen was just looking through the library. Regarding libraries such as collections is there a topic they fall under so that I know when to use them. Hoping this is a relevant question

Comment: @Grim you can use the module `collections` in many ways. I'm using it to check whether an object is iterabale or not, but I think that they fall under python data structures. They provide other data types in python in addition to `list`, `dict`... check the documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html